# Re-using Mnesia disk files for a different node

Tags: erlang, mnesia

On a node named node1@localhost I created an Mnesia schema using:
mnesia:create_schema([node()]).
and created a table using:
mnesia:create_table(tab1, [{disc_copies, [node()]}, {attributes, record_info(fields, tab1)}]).

The mnesia directory was set to "mnesia_node1". The directory was created and the DB files were created inside it.

Once the node was stopped, the DB files still exist in the directory. I hoped to re-use the DB as the mnesia DB for another node, node2.

So I started the other node using:
erl -name node2 -mnesia dir "mnesia_node1".

On node2 when I start mnesia and do a tv:start(), I see the tab1 listed in the schema. However, it shows no records. I was expecting Mnesia to use the directory as the location of all DB files.

Is there something I have missed?

Thanks,
Yash

Comment: It looks like these files are binded to the node name. Only node named node1@localhost can read them from the disk directly.